# KIOSK: Activity transition while keeping lock task to avoid "pinned" "unpinned" toasts

Tags: android, android-activity, kiosk, device-owner

I am creating a KIOSK application for a specific device. The application is the device owner.

While the application had only one activity, I solved this problem calling `startLockTask()` in `onResume()`.

The problem now, I have multiple activities and I want to make a transition from activity A to activity B in a way that activity B "replaces" activity A, meaning activity A should die, and activity B should launch.

I've done it like this

```
stopLockTask();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

I had to call `stopLockTask()` otherwise it won't finish.

Calling `startLockTask()` on activity B `onResume()` works but it's ugly because multiple toast messages will appear saying "pinned" and "unpinned".

Is there a work around to maybe kill an activity without stopping lock task? Or hiding the toast messages?

Answer (score 0):

Add your app to the `allowList` for Lock Task Mode. You aren't actually using the Lock Task Mode feature because your app isn't registered in the allowList. Instead you are using screen pinning (which can be escaped by a user).

Do this from your Device Owner:

```
// Allowlist two apps.
private static final String KIOSK_PACKAGE = "com.example.kiosk";
private static final String PLAYER_PACKAGE = "com.example.player";
private static final String[] APP_PACKAGES = {KIOSK_PACKAGE, PLAYER_PACKAGE};

// ...

Context context = getContext();
DevicePolicyManager dpm =
    (DevicePolicyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
ComponentName adminName = getComponentName(context);
dpm.setLockTaskPackages(adminName, APP_PACKAGES);
```

Fill the `APP_PACKAGES` array with your packages (only only package) that needs the Lock Task Feature.

After that, it will no longer use screen pinning in favor of Lock Task Mode. This will prevent any toast from showing up and can't be escaped by the user.

---

For reference: https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/lock-task-mode#java